# How to stop android service?

Tags: android, service, android-broadcast

This question I have searched all of related topics seems to be not answered perfectly. In General, I start Service at "LoginActivity.class" and obviously the service could be stop at any activity. In my project, I had a StopService command at onDestroy of each activities, there for, followed our rule, the Service would be stopped. But, In infact, I received error message "could not close Service..." after that, device pop up dialog "Force Close...".

In detail for your help, my Service using BroadcastReceiver to control Bluetooth communication. Hope to hear feedback from all of you. Thank you very much!

Comment: Post the **full** StackTrace and some code along with that.

Comment: There must be some other exception which is blocking it. Paste some code and stack trace.

Comment: surely will work by using this. or post your logcat

Comment: Here is my Logcat:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.example.scrollview.BTService@481a4348: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The Service is used for Blue Tooth transaction between device and another. If i don't paired or start BT connection, exitting app cause error, But after finishing transaction, quitting app is OK. ??

Comment: @Sandy: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byhex0k4V6rmYlZJRzlsRVpubFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Check out the stack track. It's due to Null Pointer Exception. You must have written something more in onDestroy() which must be throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: @Shadow: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byhex0k4V6rmQi1VSXJoVlcyb2M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Sandy:https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byhex0k4V6rmQ09oZW9BSTE0VFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Sandy: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byhex0k4V6rmcUZ0c2xiODVPOFE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: surround code from 2nd line in try/catch. I think db helper or unregister... is producing null pointer exception

Comment: @Sandy: Hi Sandy, It does not work ^^. Would you suggest some ideas

Comment: @Sandy: Thank for your help. It is exactly a "Preference To A Null Variable".

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to stop a service

```
             @Override  
            public void onDestroy()
         { 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service has been Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();
    stop(); 
    }
```

Comment: The OP has already mentioned in the question that he is stopping the service on `onDestroy()`

Comment: Here is My Activities and Service:
LoginActivity.class:

...
                // Start BlueTooth Service
  Intent startService = new Intent(this, BTService.class);
  startService(startService);
...

Comment: Here is My Activities and Service:
"LoginActivity.java":

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
...
                // Start BlueTooth Service
  Intent startService = new Intent(this, BTService.class);
  startService(startService);
...}

"GeneralInfoActivity.java":

public void onDestroy(){
...
stopService(new Intent(GeneralInfoActivity.this, BTService.class));
...}
The Service is used for Blue Tooth transaction between device and another. If i don't paired or start BT connection, exitting app cause error, But after finishing transaction, quitting app is OK. ??